# How can I separate logs in Google Cloud Logging within a single Python application?

Tags: python, logging, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-logging

I have written a Python 3.8.6 package to orchestrate and run several tasks on a Compute Engine instance, separated into several sub-packages.

```
    package/
        __init__.py
        subpackage1
        subpackage2
        subpackage3
```

I set up logging to submit logs to Cloud Logging and import the sub-package classes to do their work in the file containing the entry point (`package/__init__.py`).

```
import logging as pylogging
from google.cloud import logging
from google.cloud.logging.handlers import CloudLoggingHandler

from package.subpackage1.script1 import Class1
from package.subpackage2.script2 import Class2
from package.subpackage3.script3 import Class3

pylogging.basicConfig(level=20)
LOGGER = pylogging.getLogger()


def main():
    log_client = logging.Client()
    handler = CloudLoggingHandler(log_client, name="package")
    LOGGER.addHandler(handler)

    LOGGER.info("Starting work")

    Class1()
    Class2()
    Class3()

    LOGGER.info("Finished work")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To log from within the sub-packages I import and set up the logging similarly.

```
import logging as pylogging

pylogging.basicConfig(level=20)
LOGGER = pylogging.getLogger()


class Class1:

    def __init__(self):
        LOGGER.info("Work Class1")
```

The logs are submitted to Cloud Logging under the same log name "package", [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olOTC.png). Some sub-packages submit lots of logs, so it is hard to grasp the bigger picture of a run generally.

How do I have to set up my code to separate the logs in Cloud Logging, e.g., into different log names?

Comment: Why don't you use several handlers?

Comment: I tried to do so, but then logs get submitted multiple times and it gets messed up in Cloud Logging. Maybe I'm doing it in the wrong way... How can I use multiple handlers correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken some time today and found an answer finally.

In the main file (`package/__init__.py`) I need to set a specific name for the logger, otherwise, the root logger will be used. I've also added some debug messages to demonstrate and try different log levels. The main file looks now like this:

```
import logging as pylogging
from google.cloud import logging
from google.cloud.logging.handlers import CloudLoggingHandler

from package.subpackage1.script1 import Class1
from package.subpackage2.script2 import Class2
from package.subpackage3.script3 import Class3

pylogging.basicConfig(level=20)
LOGGER = pylogging.getLogger("package")


def main():
    log_client = logging.Client()
    handler = CloudLoggingHandler(log_client, name="package")
    LOGGER.addHandler(handler)

    LOGGER.info("Starting work")

    LOGGER.debug("Class 1")
    Class1()
    LOGGER.debug("Class 2")
    Class2()
    LOGGER.debug("Class 3")
    Class3()

    LOGGER.info("Finished work")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In the submodules, I don't have to set the basicConfig over and over again, as changing it here would cause unwanted side effects. Additionally, I have to use the same logger name as set in the `package/__init__.py` to use the same settings and send the logs to Google Cloud Logging via the defined handler. The `package/subpackage1/script1.py` looks now like this:

```
import logging as pylogging

LOGGER = pylogging.getLogger("package")


class Class1:

    def __init__(self):
        LOGGER.debug("Inside Class1")
        LOGGER.info("Work Class1")
```

Now, I want to send logs, e.g., with different levels, to a separate handler to Google Cloud logging. To achieve that, I have to create a separate logger with a different name and attach a new handler to it. It is worth noting that python logging supports period-separated hierarchical structures. This means that if I would create a child logger of the `package` logger in the script2 by naming it `package/subpackage2`, logs would be passed to both handlers and hence, result in duplicates submitted to Google Cloud logging. However, in some cases, it might make sense by applying appropriate filters to the child. In my case, `package/subpackage2/script2.py` looks like this:

```
import logging as pylogging
from google.cloud import logging
from google.cloud.logging.handlers import CloudLoggingHandler

LOGGER = pylogging.getLogger("subpackage2")
LOGGER.setLevel(10)
log_client = logging.Client()
handler = CloudLoggingHandler(log_client, name="subpackage2")
LOGGER.addHandler(handler)

class Class2:

    def __init__(self):
        LOGGER.debug("Inside Class2")
        LOGGER.info("Work Class2")
```

This sends logs to via a different handler to a different log name in Google Cloud Logging, even with modified log levels in this case. [This is how it looks in Google Cloud Logging.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxLOl.png)

This [Python logging documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial) was very helpful.